# MySQL SUM FROM Two table with wrong result

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have problem on specify the SUM of money(price) from two table . Problem on result with wrong SUM result.
**My Query :**

```
SELECT SUM(up2.price + uf1.price) AS TotalCredit
FROM user_faktorha AS uf1, u_payment AS up2
WHERE uf1.`acc_id` = '11784' && up2.`Account`='11784' && up2.`Active`='1'
```

Table `user_faktorha` Column `Price` have both positive and negative numbers .
Table `u_payment` Column `Price` Just have positive numbers .

What's wrong or problem ?

Comment: You *probably* don't need the `SUM()` function here (it's an aggregate function for use in grouped queries).  But it's hard to tell without seeing your underlying data and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest a slight change to your syntax.  Here are two alternatives:

```
SELECT up2.price + uf1.price AS TotalCredit
FROM user_faktorha AS uf1
INNER JOIN u_payment AS up2
  on uf1.acc_id = up2. Account
WHERE uf1.`acc_id` = '11784' && up2.`Active`='1';
```

Or

```
SELECT sum(up2.price + uf1.price) AS TotalCredit
FROM user_faktorha AS uf1
INNER JOIN u_payment AS up2
  on uf1.acc_id = up2. Account
WHERE uf1.`acc_id` = '11784' && up2.`Active`='1'
GROUP BY uf1.acc_id
```

Notice the [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) syntax used between the two tables and they are now joining on the `acc_id`. Also in the first version, I am not using the aggregate function I am just adding the `price` in both tables, while the second version uses the `sum()` aggregate and adds a `group by`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      SELECT  (up2.price + uf1.price) AS TotalCredit
      FROM user_faktorha AS uf1, u_payment AS up2
      WHERE uf1.`acc_id` = '11784' && up2.`Account`='11784' && up2.`Active`='1'
```

since u will add them u dont need `SUM`

Comment: `SUM()` only takes one argument.